# Jest - destructure property

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

```
export const AppLayout: React.FunctionComponent = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  // Application main layout component name
  AppLayout.displayName = getComponentName('App-Layout');
  
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  const { sendRequest } = useApiService();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        ...
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    isAuthenticated() && fetchData();
  }, []);
```

---

```
 describe('App General component', () => {
   const useAuth = jest.fn();
   const useApiService = jest.fn();

   const isAuthenticated = true;

   const props = {};

   const renderComponent = () => render(
     <AppLayout/>
   );

   it('should render without errors', () => {
     renderComponent();
   });
```

---

```
 /**
   * Validate current user exist in session
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  const isAuthenticated = React.useCallback((): boolean => {
    return Boolean(user);
  }, [user]);
```

How can I set `isAuthenticated` to `true` so I can avoid the error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of

Comment: can you provide the implementation details for `useAuth` ?

Comment: I added the function! @ToniBardinaComas

Comment: is `useAuth` a custom name for a context that you created ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const mockUseAuthIsAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => false);
const mockUseAuth = jest.fn(() => ({
  isAuthenticated: mockUseAuthIsAuthenticated,
});

jest.mock("../hooks/useAuth", mockUseAuth);

describe('My test case', () => {
  it(`should return authenticated=TRUE`, () => {
    // Given
    mockUseAuthIsAuthenticated.mockImplementationOnce(
      () => true
    );

    // When
    // assuming `render` comes from the react testing-library
    render(<ComponentThatCallsTheHook />);

    // Then
    expect(mockUseAuthIsAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    // ... more expectations
  });
});
```

Comment: I really like this approach but it returns `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockUseAuth' before initialization` for `jest.mock("../)`.

Comment: then that's caused by the way es6 imports module, there was a workaround this will try to remember/find it back

Answer (score 1):

You should mock the `useAuth` hook like this:

```
jest.mock("yourUseAuthPath", () => ({
  useAuth: () => ({
   isAuthenticated: () => true
  }),
}));

describe('App General component', () => {
...
}
```

n.b. You should replace the `yourUseAuthPath` with the correct path where you get the `useAuth` from. Example:

```
import { useAuth } from "yourUseAuthPath";
```

Some official docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials